# Using BoundList as widget

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc, extjs4.2

I have an extended bound list, and I use it as a widget. Get/set value and other works good, but: How can I add a field label before it? Example of set value:

```
setValue: function (v) {
    this.value = v;
    // TODO select selected
    var sm = this.getSelectionModel();
    var store = this.getStore();
    var rec = store.findRecord(this.valueField, v);
    sm.select(rec);
},
```

Can you help me? Or is the only solution that I have to put this bounding list in a panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get around this is to put it inside a `FieldContainer`.